# Using validation data in optimization scenarios e.g. with genetic algorithms

Tags: optimization, validation, generalization

I'm not too familiar with optimization algorithms e.g. *genetic algorithms* and I'm wondering whether it makes sense to employ a validation set in this context similarly to when we train a supervised machine learning model. Let's say we are in a chemical domain and we have experimental measures $f_1, \dots f_N$ of some quantity $f$. Then we want to optimize the parameters of a theoretical model $g(x_1, \dots , x_n, a_1, \dots,a_n)$ where $x_1, \dots x_n$ are parameters involved in the optimization and $a_1, \dots a_n$ are fixed. As the objective function we choose for example the mean absolute error:

$$MAE(f,g) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N |f_i - g_i| \, .$$

So the optimization problem is $\min_{x_1, \dots,x_n} MAE(f,g)$. My question is, should we hold out part of the initial measurements as **validation data** and at each iteration evaluating the objective both on training and validation sets? Is validation used in this type of optimization and is there a possibility of *overfitting* to training data as it usually happens with standard supervised ML models?